# Why are child applications restarted when the web.config file is modified?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I have a website that contains several child ASP.NET applications like this:

```
+ Website
|- web.config
+-- App1
| \- web.config
+-- App2
  \- web.config
```

Whenever someone modifies the `web.config` file of the Website, all Apps are restarted and the user sessions are destroyed.

The problem is that App1 for instance is updated rarely, but the Website itself several times a day. Now the users of App1 are complaining about lost sessions.

Is there an easier way than moving the App1 folder out of the Website folder?

Comment: No, this is by design. Why do you alter your web.config multiple times a day?

Comment: One reason is that the web.config contains caching times for regions of the site. New regions are often added or existing caching times changed. Web.config also contains a lot of URL rewriting settings that are updated a lot as old legacy code is converted from ASP to ASP.NET.

Comment: The other option is to move the session to outproc...

Comment: We solved the problem by changing sessionState in App1's web.config to StateServer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx Some modification of the code was needed, because you can't serializale every kind of object into the Session using StateServer mode. Thanks for your help!